# Spam being sent via sendmail on server. How do I trace the source?

Tags: sendmail

Ther eis spam being sent from my server right now and I have no idea where it is originating from.  Here is the log entry from one of the emails:

`Dec 11 20:04:55 ip-10-170-94-31 sendmail[20858]: sBBK4rfZ020856: to=<anderson_saan@hotmail.com>, ctladdr=<apache@ip-10-170-94-31.us-west-1.compute.internal> (48/48), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=126531, relay=relay.jangosmtp.net. [64.56.118.248], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (6893 bytes received in 00:00:00; Message id 201412112004570841 accepted for delivery)`

How can I go about tracing this back to whatever is sending the emails?

Comment: You can start by grep queue ID or grep sBBK4rfZ020856 in maillog

Comment: There's a fair chance that it's from a cracked php website. Something like http://www.matteomattei.com/how-to-log-email-sent-from-php-through-mail-function/ can wrap the php mail call and grab some meaningful logs, which often include things like from addresses that might relate to one of your websites.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem by looking in the Apache logs.  Apparently, the FTP password was hacked and there was a `post.php` file placed in all of the web directories that allowed them to send emails.

Answer (score 1):

If your mail server is spamming, stop it and look at the queue files for clues.

If it could be from PHP, add a `mail.log` directive where appropriate (eg Apache php_admin_value).